# Reactive sliderInput ends in same slider

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I'd like to create a range slider where when selecting one end of the slider updates the other end of the same slider. I know the trick is in observing a change at one end and using it to update the other end. However, I am getting a behaviour where the sliders are flipping back and forth, and I can't figure out why it's not settling.

For the sake of this example, I'd like the sliders to be centred within a 0-100 scale, so that when `input$slider[1]` is set to `10` then `input$slider[2]` moves to `90`, and when `input$slider[2]` is moved to `80`, `input$slider[1]` is moved to `20`. Example (buggy) code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("slidertest"),
  verbatimTextOutput("values")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sliderends <- reactiveValues(end=c(NULL,NULL))

  observe({
    sliderends$end[1] <- 100-input$slider[2]
  })

  observe({
    sliderends$end[2] <- 100-input$slider[1]
  })

  output$slidertest <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider","Update Ends?", min = 0, max=100, value=c(sliderends$end[1],sliderends$end[2]))
  })

  output$values <- renderText({paste(input$slider[1], input$slider[2], sliderends$end[1], sliderends$end[2], sep=";")})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

An explanation of what I'm doing wrong and working suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your slider input get into an infinite loop.

`input$slider[1]` change → `input$slider[2]` change → `input$slider[1]` change ......

You can use `reactiveValues` to check whether the start value of `sliderinput` changed or the end value of `sliderinput` changed, then use `updateSliderInput` to update the value of your `sliderinput`.

See the following code :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # uiOutput("slidertest"),
  sliderInput("slider","Update Ends?", min = 0, max=100,value=c(0,100) ),
  verbatimTextOutput("values")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sliderends <- reactiveValues(start=0,end=100)

  observeEvent(input$slider,{
    if(input$slider[1]!=sliderends$start){
      #start value change
      sliderends$start<-input$slider[1]
      updateSliderInput( session,"slider","Update Ends?", min = 0, max=100,value=c( input$slider[1] , 100-input$slider[1] ) )
    }else if(input$slider[2]!=sliderends$end){
      #end value chagne 
      sliderends$end<-input$slider[2]
      updateSliderInput( session,"slider","Update Ends?", min = 0, max=100,value=c( 100-input$slider[2] , input$slider[2] ) )
    }
  })

  output$values <- renderText({paste(input$slider[1], input$slider[2], sliderends$start, sliderends$end, sep=";")})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```